# Lua error to create a class

Tags: class, lua, love2d

I'm trying to create a class for my game and I got this error (shown in love2d): **attempt to index upvalue 'World' (a boolean value)**

This is my World file I made:

```
local World = {}
World.__index = World

function World:new(meter, gravity)
    setmetatable({}, World)

    -- Set physics parameters
    love.physics.setMeter(meter)
    self.world = love.physics.newWorld(0, gravity*meter, true)

    -- Load background
    self.background = love.graphics.newImage("imgs/background.png")

    return self
end

function World:update(dt)

end

function World:draw()
    love.graphics.draw(self.background)
end

function World:destroy()
    -- Destroy the world
    self.world:destroy()
end
```

And here I call the world:

```
local World = require("world")

function love.load()
    -- Build the world
    world = World:new(32, 9.81)
end
```

What is wrong? Anyway, what is the best way for make a class in Lua?

Answer (score 5):

In the `world.lua` file, put a `return World` at the end:

```
.
.
.
function World:destroy()
    -- Destroy the world
    self.world:destroy()
end

-- Add line below
return World
```

Comment: Oww it worket! But why do I have to put this return if I already returned self in the new method?

Comment: @Jazz So that require returns the World table.

Comment: But now I got this doubt: I'm making a module or a class?

Comment: @Jazzguy They are the same. Other languages call it class, package etc, lua has modules.